# UITableViewCell - heightForRowAtIndexPath - Animation Speed xcode objective c

Tags: xcode, animation, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

When changing the row height for a cell with

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (a)
    return 55
  else
    return 266
}
```

Then,

```
[aTableView beginUpdates];
```

The table cell will animate to the height if it has changed.

Is there anyway to control the speed of this animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No way to control the speed of the animation of table view. 
Maybe you can write a custom table view, then you can control many things as you like.